# Testcafe: using Test Controler in boundTestRun not working

Tags: node.js, web-component, e2e-testing, shadow-dom, testcafe

I'm trying to work with shadow roots in my Testcafe project. It's a little bit complicated to deal with it. I create a custom function that behaves the same as Selector().find() but I struggle with this error :

```
The "boundTestRun" option value is expected to be a test controller.
```

when I'm doing as documented [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/edge-cases-and-limitations.html#calling-selectors-from-nodejs-callbacks) :

```js
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe'

getInShadowRoot = Selector( 
        // More code here
    )
const boundedGetInShadowRoot = this.getInShadowRoot.with({ boundTestRun: t })
```

I create a gist to illustrate my problem: https://gist.github.com/HugoDel/a600f3e120674e3f255884f3dc84fee3

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**
I finally get rid of it since I don't need to add `.with({ boundTestRun: t })` to make it work.

Comment: Could you please provide a page with which I can run the provided test code?

Comment: Well... I can't give you the exact website but maybe I can reproduce a sample of code. Anyway, this error happened during compilation time...